# Blocking execution until user selects an option from the browser's download modal

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, download, modal-dialog

I'm using `window.location.href = some_url` in a javascript bit. This brings up a menu from the browser, like so:

[image]

This is already happening within a promise - I have other .then() after, but I'd like them to hold on until the user has selected something from that menu.

Any way to access this? Code bits:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        })
        .done(function(response, jqXHR){
            new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                if (response.download){
                    console.log("downloading files sent.... ")
                    window.location.href=response.download.url

                    // I'd like to block here on the popup window before moving

                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    console.log("No downloads.")
                    resolve(response);
                }
                return response
            })
                .then(...)
```

Comment: You can't really intercept this. Some browsers may not show the popup, some may simply navigate to that resource (and unload the current page), some may offer the download modal.

Comment: Yeah, the more I was thinking about this, the more I was doubting this was viable.

I guess I'll have to build a blob instead & work with that. Seems messy and I was somewhat trying to avoid it, but...

Comment: What are you going to do with the blob? I doubt the situation is any different there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the real answer is you need to not be lazy and use something like a blob instead. Client-side, something like that:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        })
        .done(function(response, jqXHR){
            console.log("POST success,")
            if (response.download.url) {
                console.log("content to download")
                fetch(response.download.url)
                    .then(function (resp){
                        let blob = resp.blob()
                        const header = resp.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
                        let filename = header.split(';')[1].split('=')[1];
                        response["filename"] = filename
                        return blob
                        // return resp
                    })
                    .then( function(blob) {
                        // blob = resp.blob()
                        const blob_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                        const a = document.createElement('a')
                        a.style.display = "none"
                        a.href = blob_url
                        a.download = response.filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob_url)
                        // alert("download should be finished now")
                        return response
                    })
                    .then(function (response){
                        if (response.current_page && response.current_page.refresh) {
                            console.log("Refreshing page...")
                            location.reload(true);
                            console.log("Done.")
                        } else {
                            console.log("No refresh.")
                        }
                        return response
                    })
                    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)} )
```

Then server-side - I'm using django, but the details would be similar in other frameworks:

```
        logger.info(f"Creating tmp file for pdf response")
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
            file.write(pdf)
            file.seek(0)
            stream = file.read()
        # build the http response
        httpresponse = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf;', content=stream)
        httpresponse['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={value["filename"]}'
        httpresponse['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'
        return httpresponse
```

This works, because then I'm waiting on the fetch() call to finish before I move on to build the blob() & recover it locally. In other words, the "waiting" is managed by the fetch()' promise, and it only moves on once the server returned the file.

Then I can refresh the page without worrying, since I have the data in the browser's cache at that point. Loosing the state with a reload() at that point is fine.

Comment: Oh, so what you actually wanted to wait for is the download to finish, not the user closing the modal window?

Comment: Well, I guess I wasn't 100% clear on what I wanted myself. My initial question somewhat asked about a specific answer (e.g. waiting for user action), as opposed to really stating the problem (e.g. need download to finish before moving on). Not thinking straight theses days I guess